# Stata: How to deactivate automatic omission because of collinearity

Tags: regression, stata

Is there any possibility to tell stata not to automatically omit variables due to (near) collinearity in regressions? I use dummy variables to deal with outliers in my sample; i.e. they take the value 1 for only one observations and are zero for all others. Stata drops most of these dummies as it recognizes them as collinear, which of course is true, but they're not perfectly collinear and I'd like to keep them in the regression.

Comment: This kind of question is not a good fit for SO. There is no code and no question about programming. It's a question about how Stata works and how to use it. Statalist is a better forum for this. You got a good answer quickly from a Stata expert, so that's fine, but in future please direct these questions elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stata drops variables that "predicts failure perfeclty" even though the correlation between the variables isn't 1 or -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371631/stata-drops-variables-that-predicts-failure-perfeclty-even-though-the-correlat)

Answer (score 2):

Stata will only drop perfectly collinear variables, so the answer is "no, you cannot".

Comment: How can I find out which of the explanatory variables are perfectly collinear? Is this information stored somewhere when using the regress command?

Comment: @jeffrey use the command `corr` to search for the perfectly collinear ones. If there are too many numbers to look at, rank them with `matrix corrvector=vec(r(C))` new line `matvsort corrvector sortedvector` new line `matrix list sortedvector` (See https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-10/msg00352.html ).

Comment: @jeffrey Perfect negative correlation would be more evident with the option `decrease` on `matvsort`.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered similar question yesterday. Yes, it is possible to fix it [I have].

Bivariate cross tabulation does not show the problem. Try this:

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/completely-determined-in-logistic-regression/index.html

First confirm that this is what is happening [collinear]. (For your data, replace x1 and x2 with the independent variables of your model.)

1. Number covariate patterns:

   egen pattern = group(x1 x2)
2. Identify pattern with only one outcome:

   logit y x1 x2 predict p summarize p

   the extremes of p will be almost 0 or almost 1 tab pattern if p < 1e-7 // (use a value here slightly bigger than the min)

   or in the above use "if p > 1 - 1e-7" if p is almost 1 list x1 x2 if pattern == XXXX // (use the value here from the tab step)

   the above identifies the covariate pattern
3. The covariate pattern that predicts outcome perfectly may be meaningful to the researcher or may be an anomaly due to having many variables in the model.
4. Now you must get rid of the collinearity:

   logit y x1 x2 if pattern ~= XXXX // (use the value here from the tab step)
   note that there is collinearity *You can omit the variable that logit drops or drop another one.
5. Refit the model with the collinearity removed:

   logit y x1

You may or may not want to include the covariate pattern that predicts outcome perfectly. It depends on the answer to (3). If the covariate pattern that predicts outcome perfectly is meaningful, you may want to exclude these observations from the model:

```
logit y x1 if pattern ~= XXXX
```

Here one would report

Covariate pattern such and such predicted outcome perfectly The best model for the rest of the data is ....xyz

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It's how do I change the data so that the problem doesn't bite. That's close, but not the same question, and there are now statistical and ethical issues too!

Comment: It does answer the question perfectly. This is the very issue that my answer deals with. I have used it and it worked perfectly. Other people I know used it. This is the only solution to collinearity caused by the use of binary values. Please [the owner of the question] apply my fix and let me know.

Comment: Question was "Is there any possibility to tell Stata not to automatically omit variables due to (near) collinearity in regressions?". Your answer is different. It's a reasonable stance to say or imply that one should be asking a different question, but I stick by my comment. The answer by @Maarten Buis (although not what people may want to hear) is bang on.

Comment: "Is there any possibility to tell Stata not to automatically omit variables due to (near) collinearity in regressions?" YES, there is! Try my solution and it will work. I have had the same issue [running probit/logit and ols regs] few days ago and solved it with the above. Nick, I'm not here to convince you [I'm here to help the person who asked the question] - to be honest I don't see you posting any solutions.

Comment: Not persuaded at all. The OP wants a switch "please don't do this". You can't provide one because it isn't possible, but I'd be astonished if leaving out the data that are awkward qualifies for anyone. Three strikes now, and I am out.